# Using MatLab to calculate signal:noise ratio

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How do you use MatLab to calculate the SNR?

**Update**

I only have one file, not two like in the example and it's a .tif.

Comment: *Calculate* or *estimate* the SNR ? You need to understand the theory behind this before you get into implementing it with Matlab.

Answer (score 7):

First Google result for [Matlab SNR](http://www.dsprelated.com/showmessage/72809/1.php). Copied from there, in dB:

```
snr = 10*log10(sum(clean.^2) ./ sum(noise.^2))
```

EDIT: The signal-to-noise ratio cannot be computed without knowing the signal power and noise power. With only knowledge of the observed (i.e., received) signal, one can blindly *estimate* the SNR, but this is an open research topic. See "blind quality measurement".

Answer (score 3):

Mean of `noisy` and `clean` should be zero:

```
signal = var(clean(:));
noise  = var(noisy(:)); 

s2n = 10*log10( signal / noise );
```

From: *[A comparison and analysis of different PDE-based approaches for image enhancement](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~ramtin/ICSPCS/ICSPCS%2707/papers/16.pdf)*, page 4.

Comment: If you are just calculating the variance, does it matter what the mean is? The result will still be the same if you add a scalar to either `clean` or `noisy`.

Answer (score 0):

On the input side:

```
Calculate DB1 = 10*log10(var(noiseSignal))
Calculate DB2 = 10*log10(var(cleanSpeechSignal))
```

The SNR is = DB2 - DB1